# Custom Button not showing my images for pushed state

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios

In code, I set the following:
                    btnLogo.SetImage(UIImage.FromBundle("images/Zouak_logo_button.png"), UIControlState.Normal);
                    btnLogo.SetImage(UIImage.FromBundle("images/Zouak_logo_button_pushed.png"), UIControlState.Selected);

I couldn't find a UIControlState.Pressed or Pushed or anything along those lines. When the button is pushed of course it isn't showing the version of the image that I want. Do I need to do this in the Click event manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your syntax is kind of strange, but I guess that you want to do:

```
UIButton *btn = [[UIButton alloc] init];
[btn setImage:uiimg forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

Comment: Where uiimg = UIImage.FromBundle("images/Zouak_logo_button_pushed.png"), of course.

Comment: I see my error, it's that I thought it was for Selected state, not Highlighted. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Do this for all states:

```
UIImage *newNormalImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"images/Zouak_logo_button.png"];
[btnLogo setBackgroundImage:newNormalImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
// Image for highlighted state
UIImage *newHighlightedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"mages/Zouak_logo_button_pushed.png"];
[btnLogo setBackgroundImage:newHighlightedImage forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
// Image for selected state
UIImage *newSelectedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"mages/Zouak_logo_button_pushed.png"];
[btnLogo setBackgroundImage:newSelectedImage forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```